# Group by and value_counts - return results as columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DF of the following:

```
    value     name     
      A      Steven     
      A      Steven    
      A      Ron    
      B      Joe     
      B      Steven     
      B      Ana
```

I want to perform a value_counts() operation on the name column so the output will be a DF where the columns are the counters of the values :

```
     value  Steven Ron  Joe Ana   
      A       2     1    0   0
      B       1     0    1   1
```

Tried a group by+value_counts and than transposing the results but didn't reached the output.

Answer (score 1):

It is `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.value, df.name).reset_index().rename_axis(None,1)

Out[62]:
  value  Ana  Joe  Ron  Steven
0     A    0    0    1       2
1     B    1    1    0       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `groupby` and `value_counts` like this:

```
df.groupby('value')['name'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
name value  Ana  Joe  Ron  Steven
0        A    0    0    1       2
1        B    1    1    0       1
```